Nugget Package - consult security issue in solution VS2022
I saw in solution explore in Visual Studio 2022 problem with Nuget Packages with vulnerabilities,  exist any command get that information?visual studio explore
the objetive is List all vulnerability Nuget packages in the solution for take action

Regarding using commands to get vulnerable Nuget packages, I recommend the following method:
1: Go to Build > Clean and rebuild your solution.
2: Go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console. Use the following command:
dotnet list package --vulnerable
